# Can I have database without installing SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012

I want to build an ASP.NET website with Entity Framework 5 but I do not have permission to install SQL Server on my system, is it possible? If yes, how? If not, any alternative, like files etc...

Comment: do you have permission to install anything? use external binaries/assemblies?

Comment: sql server compact edition? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin : I can install packages in visual studio via nuget, that's all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't install anything, then I'm afraid you're stuck with embedded databases like SQL Server Compact Edition or Sqlite. (and some NOSQL databases as well, I believe some of them don't require a server)

Just don't forget about one thing - embedded databases usually aren't enough for web environment.

For instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591002/how-can-i-use-sqlite-in-a-c-sharp-project
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx

Comment: [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) seems pretty cool too, messed around with it for a couple hours once.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was dual-licensed like mySql.  So you can't even use it on a web site for free?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, as far as I know, only for open source projects.

Comment: @walther - Did a little digging and it seems you're right.  Guess I won't be using that any time soon.

Comment: Agreed, that was a killer for me, too. Too bad they don't have an Express edition or something.

Comment: @MikeCole In my Office, i would have to go through lots of formalities to get any software installed as it is Licensed. So i thought of trying myself.

Comment: @RajeshMishra it's probably something you'll have to end up doing. The alternatives are painful.

Comment: @walther I would really appreciate if you could refer me some links that would help me doing this. Don't Know where to start from.

Comment: @RajeshMishra Most offices that have formal processes to install server software also discourage the use of "compact" databases to get around those processes.

Comment: @RajeshMishra, really a big problem to put that into Google search :) Updated the answer with some links.

Answer (score 1):

You could offload the database platform entirely to a remote Azure database; there's lots of info on this online, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg190738.aspx) might be a good starting point.

Comment: I appreciate your help, will have a look first then will raise further query.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to host your database on another service like [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/) or Microsoft [Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336230.aspx).